# Node.js: can't get socket.io to work with express, getting 404s on script file

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use express to serve static pages with express that communicate with socket.io.  I keep running into problem after problem.  I have done so many things, and googled so many times, that I can't believe I haven't found an answer to my specific problem.  I keep running into places that show you the server, or show you the client, but not the other that communicates with it.  Or both, but not with express.  When I throw express into the mix, I start getting 404s and I them move my socket.io client scripts around and still can't seem to get it to work.  This is where I'm at right now, though this is about my 20th configuration.

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static('html'));
});

app.listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A socket connected!');
});
```

Client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  socket.send('testing');
</script>
```

I have tried changing the src to /html/socket.io.js (and copied all necessary files from the dist directory to /html), tried creating a scripts directory in the html directory, tried linking to socket.io's cdn, and I keep getting 404s.  I know it's something stupid and simple that I'm messing up, I just can't figure it out for the life of me.  Thanks!

edit: all I want to do right now is serve the index.html page and print to the server console when it sees the connection.

Comment: Never hear anyone using express with socket.io, most people generally use connect.

Comment: Well, that's just wrong. Express works perfectly fine with socket.io

Comment: What happens if you remove socket.io and render some pure html? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, it renders regular html just fine.  I feel like the static file configuration is somehow messing up how it looks for the socket.io.js file.  I'm going to try creating a regular js file with an alert on it and see if I can get it to locate that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just have a look at the examples from [here](http://socket.io/#how-to-use). I got it to work with express 3 by changing `app.listen` to `server.listen`. I think the routing that socket.io sets up is specific to the http server and does not use the express routing mechanism.

Comment: Argh.  I've been through all of those examples, but none of them dealt with express and I could never get them to work together.  Changing app.listen to server.listen worked, and I'm still serving html pages through express without issue.  Now that I look at it, it totally makes sense.  I was attaching socket.io to express when it needed to be listening to the http server.  The examples I've been seeing shows it listening to express, but that's before they changed express to no longer return the http server.  Thanks!  Now I'll have something to play with all weekend.